# How to get virtual directory in mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, virtual-directory

I am working on a .net core application where I need the application path to the virtual directory. I do not want the physical path, I want it in form of url like:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/mydirectory
```

I have tried with `Request.Host` but it only gives me  `http://www.mywebsite.com` without the virtual directory path.

Any help on this appreciated!

Comment: Try this - `Request.Path`

Comment: Where do you need to get the virtual directory path? In a controller? Startup.cs? Somewhere else?

Comment: want to get in controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `IUrlHelper` to resolve the base-path of the application. If the application is not hosted within a virtual directory the returned path is just empty...

```
IUrlHelper url = ...
string virtualDirectory = url.Content("~");
```